# How to Link Excel to SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel

I have a problem on how will I connect my excel to SharePoint. I have created a list in SharePoint and I need those data sync in excel that I want to create. I'm using excel 2016 and SharePoint 2016. Please refer to this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-a-SharePoint-List-Power-Query-3226f248-f8b3-4777-82ce-b4ed04dedaaf?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) because I think this is what I supposed to do. The problem there is that I can't see the "SharePoint List" option in my excel.

[image]

Comment: Excel can't sync **to** SharePoint, you can open a SharePoint list **read-only** in Excel, and that is it

Microsoft Access can do read/write operations to SharePoint

Comment: how can I open it as ready only Sir? actually I need only to get the data and put it in my excel and when I make a changes in my sharepoint list it will also update in the excel

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, sorry for very late answer, but indeed you can sync 2-way, with a 3rd party software, Synchronizer for Excel and SharePoint, https://www.synchronizer-for-excel-and-sharepoint.com. It will export your existing list to Excel, let you add rows in Excel, then sync it back to SharePoint as often as you want. After the sync, Excel also gets the updates from SharePoint, so that both always stay in Sync (Disclaimer: It is developed and maintained by my company.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the steps in this article: 
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Export-a-list-to-Excel-in-SharePoint-Online-40f4b5cd-cb8a-4106-817e-4a0bf7cd68b5

If your list on the sharePoint gets updated, you will need to Refresh connection in excel in order to get the updated data from the SharePoint List.

[image]

Comment: I'm getting problem with exporting it to excel. But how will I have a sharepoint list option in sources

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the article?  What is the error? you need to provide more details for a precise answer.